# Manually upload mapping.txt to crashlytics

Tags: android, crashlytics

I have an old build Android apk with obfuscated code. I have the mapping.txt. Is there a way to manually upload the mapping.txt to Crashlytics without requiring to rebuild the apk again? I do not have to correct versions of jdk, android sdk, etc to ensure I build the exact same apk binary.

Alternatively, can I use gradle on my current version to upload mapping.txt for a previous version?

Answer (score 4):

Crashlytics automatically uploads the mapping file.

You can check the status on Mac by looking in:

```
~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics/com.crashlytics.tools/crashlytics.log
```

If your mapping file has not been uploaded, rebuild from same machine. The deobfuscation file will be kept in the `deobs` directory. After upload, it will be moved to `deobs_uploaded`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is feasible. My guess is that Crashlytics associates a unique ID to each build, and that ID in turn is used to retrieve the corresponding mapping.

The only thing you can do is manually de-obfuscate the code using the `retrace` script.

Comment: But but? In what way is crashlytics than usable for android?
Even in the Play Store you can upload a mapping.txt file...